# ORA-12560: Tns Protocol Adapter Error + ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run a bat script which should perform the automatic deployment of a database, along with other structures, but I have several problems when I run the file.

I have installed Oracle 19, set my ORACLE_HOME to the folder path and also ORACLE_SID is set to "orcl". I have also started the OracleServiceORCL from services and when I run my bat script, I get more errors:

```
>>>  STEP 0 => Running prerequisites with dba role user  <<<
_____________________________________________________________
BEGIN dbms_output.put_line('Connected user is '||USER); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

The file looks like this:

```
SET serveroutput on
SET pagesize 5000
SET long 5000
SET pages 500
SET linesize 300
SET echo on
SET serveroutput on
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 

prompt ##########################################
prompt ###### Start deploying SABD project ######
prompt ##########################################
prompt

-- Setting deploy variables
define srcDB_path='C:\Users\mihaelad\WSOP\main\main\src\database'
define adminSABD='SABDADM'
define userSABD='SABDUSER'
define passAdmSABD='SABDADM'
define passUserSABD='SABDUSER'

prompt _____________________________________________________________
prompt >>>  STEP 0 => Running prerequisites with dba role user  <<<
prompt _____________________________________________________________
SET feedback off
EXECUTE dbms_output.put_line('Connected user is '||USER);
--SET feedback on
@runWithDba.sql
prompt
prompt
SET feedback off;
EXECUTE dbms_lock.sleep(2);
SET feedback on;

connect &&adminSABD/&&passAdmSABD
SET serveroutput on
prompt ______________________________________________
prompt >>>  STEP 1 => Creating SABDADM objects  <<<
prompt ______________________________________________
SET feedback off
EXECUTE dbms_output.put_line('Connected user is '||USER);
SET feedback on
@sabdadm/master.sql

connect &&userSABD/&&passUserSABD
SET serveroutput on
prompt ______________________________________________
prompt >>>  STEP 2 => Creating SABDUSER objects  <<<
prompt ______________________________________________
SET feedback off
EXECUTE dbms_output.put_line('Connected user is '||USER);
SET feedback on
@sabduser/master.sql

exit
```

and also the error regarding TNS: ORA-12560. I will also provide my listener.ora:

```
# This is a sample listener.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

LISTENER =
 (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))
 )

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
      (SID_DESC=
         (SID_NAME=dg4odbc)
         (ORACLE_HOME=C:\Users\mihaelad\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
         (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
      )
  )

#CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER = 0
```

and also the tnsnames.ora:

```
# This is a sample tnsnames.ora that contains the NET8 parameters that are
# needed to connect to an HS Agent

dg4odbc  =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dg4odbc))
    (HS=OK)
  )
```

I also tried to set ORACLE_SID with "dg4odbc", as mentioned in the tnsnames, but same errors appeared.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown how you're making the initial connection. Presumably the listener is running, as well as the database; though unless you've set TWO_TASK/LOCAL the `connect` calls in the SQL script will avoid TNS anyway. And is you are using TNS, why are you using SID rather than service name?

Comment: I did not make an initial connection, maybe that is the issue ? how can I do that?

Comment: So what is throwing the ORA-12560? How are you running SQL\*Plus from your bat script? Please include at least that part of the script, along with how any variables it uses are set (or the whole script if it isn't very long).

Comment: If you don't make an initial connection, why would you expect any commands against the database to work?  Please update your post to show the script that is calling sqlplus.  Also, your tnsnames and listener config are for a transparent gateway connection to a non-oracle database.  Why is that?

Comment: It appears that you are repeatedly posting a question, getting some comments, deleting the question, and then posting an almost identical question (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932795/ora-12560-tns-protocol-adapter-error-and-ora-01034-oracle-not-available?noredirect=1#comment116577277_65932795 was deleted just before you posted this).  Please feel free to edit your question if you need to clarify something.  But it is not efficient to have various people ask many of the same things in separate sets of comments.